# Return records where there are no duplicates in one field

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have the following (sample) script

```
Select field1, field2, field3, field4, field5 from tblsample
```

which may return

```
field1, field2, field3, field4, field5
123     etc     etc     etc     etc
123     etc     etc     etc     etc
123     etc     etc     etc     etc
456     etc     etc     etc     etc
789     etc     etc     etc     etc
789     etc     etc     etc     etc
125     etc     etc     etc     etc
```

How should I write a query to return only those rows which don't have duplicate values in "field 1". for example for the table above the expected result is:

```
field1, field2, field3, field4, field5
456     etc     etc     etc     etc
125     etc     etc     etc     etc
```

please note that the rows with 123 and 789 are not included in the result, since there are multiple rows with those values.

Comment: If field2 has different values how will you show field 2 value(s)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use analytic `count()` in such situations:

**<sup>[demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/83b2cd/417)</sup>**

```
select field1, field2, field3, field4, field5
  from (select field1, field2, field3, field4, field5, 
               count(1) over (partition by field1) cnt
          from tblsample)
  where cnt = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select field1, max( field2), max(field3), max(field4), max( 
 field5)
 from tblsample
group by field1
having count(*) = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Without using max() function;

```
select *
from tblsample
where field1 in 
(select field1 
 from tblsample 
 group by field1 
 having count(1)=1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * 
from (select *,COUNT(*) over (partition by field1) row 
from tblsample) x 
where row = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

without using window function:

```
SELECT *
 FROM tblsample t INNER JOIN (SELECT
                            count(field1),
                            field1
                          FROM tblsample
                          GROUP BY field1
                          HAVING count(field1) = 1) a
ON a.field1 = t.field1
```